# Django filter - search with string with symbols

Tags: python, django, search, filter

I used icontains for filtering data which equivalents to 'LIKE'.

But it won't trigger filter for strings with other ASCII characters e.g. / , ' , & , etc.

Here's a sample code

```
Chartofaccount.objects.all().filter(title__icontains=search).filter(isdeleted=0).order_by('-pk')
```

which works perfectly well when searching. But when I search for words like

```
cats & dogs
```

It would not return any results, same with other stated characters.

Comment: Please be more specific. [Edit] your question to show your actual code. Then provide a few test cases for input, what you expect that input to match, and what happens instead.

Comment: Look into Django's [iregex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#iregex)

Comment: Look into django's `Q` objects for complex filtering.